# NullPointerException on GoogleMap.addMarker error

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I got a `NullPointerException` on `GoogleMap` add `marker`.
Please help me solving this issue.

error:

```
08-10 12:49:20.787 6670-6670/com.example.taxiproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.taxiproject, PID: 6670
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
at com.example.taxiproject.DriverPositionActivity$GetLocations.onPostExecute(DriverPositionActivity.java:523)
at com.example.taxiproject.DriverPositionActivity$GetLocations.onPostExecute(DriverPositionActivity.java:437)
```

This is `DriverPositionActivity.java:523` line code:

```
markers=new HashMap<Marker, Driver>();
                removeMarkers();

                for (int i = 0; i < drivers.size(); i++) {
                    MarkerOptions mark=new MarkerOptions();
                    mark.position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(drivers.get(i).getLatitude()),Double.parseDouble(drivers.get(i).getLongitude())));
                    mark.title(drivers.get(i).getName());
                    mark.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.taxi));
                    //mark.snippet(drivers.get(i).getInfo()+","+drivers.get(i).getCost()+" Rs.pKm, Ph. "+drivers.get(i).getNumber());
        ----------------->  Marker m=googleMap.addMarker(mark);
                    mapMarker.add(m);
                    markers.put(m, drivers.get(i));
}
```

This is `DriverPositionActivity.java:437` line code:

```
class GetLocations extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String toastText="Internet Problem";
    String regiresult="";
    int success=0;
    int error=0;
    String errmsg="Server is down";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(con);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating drivers locations. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... para) {

        List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json=jparser.makeHttpRequest(getDataUrl, "POST", params);

        try {
            success=json.getInt("success");
            if(success==1){

                drivers=new ArrayList<Driver>();

                JSONArray sounds=json.getJSONArray("location");
                for (int i = 0; i < sounds.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj=sounds.getJSONObject(i);
                    Driver d=new Driver();
                    d.setId(jobj.getString("id"));
                    d.setName(jobj.getString("name"));
                    d.setEmail(jobj.getString("email"));
                    d.setNumber(jobj.getString("number"));
                    d.setLatitude(jobj.getString("latitude"));
                    d.setLongitude(jobj.getString("longitude"));
                    d.setInfo(jobj.getString("info"));
                    d.setCost(jobj.getString("cost"));


                    drivers.add(d);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error=1;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            error=1;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s+" "+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if(error==1){
            if(Util.isConnectingToInternet(con)){
                Toast.makeText(con,"Server is down. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Util.showNoInternetDialog(con);
            }
            return;
        }

        if(success==0){
            Toast.makeText(con,"Data loading failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (success==1){

            markers=new HashMap<Marker, Driver>();
            removeMarkers();

            for (int i = 0; i < drivers.size(); i++) {
                MarkerOptions mark=new MarkerOptions();
                mark.position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(drivers.get(i).getLatitude()),Double.parseDouble(drivers.get(i).getLongitude())));
                mark.title(drivers.get(i).getName());
                mark.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.taxi));
                //mark.snippet(drivers.get(i).getInfo()+","+drivers.get(i).getCost()+" Rs.pKm, Ph. "+drivers.get(i).getNumber());
                Marker m=googleMap.addMarker(mark);
                mapMarker.add(m);
                markers.put(m, drivers.get(i));
            }
            scheduleThread();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not declared `googleMap` object.

Comment: hi sir i have declared object as private GoogleMap googleMap; in activity class sir. please advise me to solve this issue. thank u sir